# Spring SAML Extension, how to enforce WantAssertionsSigned in code instead of sp metadata

Tags: spring-saml

Is there any way to enforce the AssertionsSigned in code instead of service provider metadata?

Currently our IDP sends the Assetion signed and we have WantAssertionsSigned in metadata as true, but instead of having that in sp.xml can we configure in code so that no one can change it to false?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to send the wantAssertionSigned=true only for few requests and not all.

Take a look at the implementation of the class MetadataGenerator. Have never tried it but I guess you would need to add a custom class extending MetadataGenerator instead and have your conditional logic in it to set true/false to the wantAssertionSigned attribute and also generate/load the SP metadata on every call and dynamically so as to have the condition executed every time.